# TypeError: parser_f() got multiple values for argument 'sep'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have used this code to convert the .csv file to .xlsx. But it's throwing an error.

*If I have removed the sep=',' in the code then it is converting the file but the entire data is in a single column instead of their expected columns.*

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(open('duplicate1.csv'),'Sheet1',sep=',',delimiter=None, index_col=0)

df.to_excel('duplicateexcel.xlsx',encoding='utf-8')
```

Expected:

```
This should convert the .csv file to .xlsx.
```

Actual Output:

```
TypeError: parser_f() got multiple values for argument 'sep'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(open('duplicate1.csv'),index_col=0)
df.to_excel('duplicateexcel.xlsx',encoding='utf-8')
```

Use this you dont need to write sep=',' it's default 
also delimeter=none is also default 
hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You have probably solved this problem a long time ago. I just want to share that I had the same problem and found out that whatever you write after the first comma python would consider that you are passing the "sep" parameter.

Your code:

`df = pd.read_csv(open('duplicate1.csv'),'Sheet1',sep=',',delimiter=None, index_col=0)`

You should delete "Sheet1" that is what python is reading as argument for "sep", plus you also pass "sep=','. That's why python is returning error multiple values for "sep".

Try this instead:

`df = pd.read_csv(open('duplicate1.csv'),sep=',',delimiter=None, index_col=0)`